# How to add work item as child to parent?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I've been able to find documentation on creating work items via the VSTS REST API, however, I haven't been able to find anything creating a work item and linking it to a Parent work item.

Searching around, I've seen some links regarding a `System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse`, but no API reference on how it works, or how it might link a work item to a parent work item id. Link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/link-type-element-reference?view=vsts)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To add a work item with parent work item linked, you should use the REST API as:

```
POST https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=4.1
```

application/json-patch+json:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "title"},
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
      "url": "URL for the parent work item"
    }
    }

]
```

Below is the example to create a task `mytask` with parent work item (work item id is `184`) linked:

```
POST https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/Git2/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=4.1
```

application/json-patch+json:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "mytask"},
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
      "url": "https://marinaliu.visualstudio.com/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4/_apis/wit/workItems/184"
    }
    }

]
```