# How to add a link "parent/child" between 2 certain already created work item - Azure Boards

Tags: azure, azure-devops, veracode, workitem, azure-boards

Currently, we use Veracode in our ci enviroment(Azure Pipelines) for security check. Veracode has a azuredevops plugin, that creates flaws as work items(either bug, task etc) in azure boards. However, we created a certain epic, "Security Issues", and we expect that there's a way to link via pipeline, a already created work item to it as a parent/child.

I've been searching for methods (first time working with Azure API's), and I didnt found any specific way to achieve this integration( I did see this, but in this case, they create a work item, instead of linking 2 that already exist [How to add work item as child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518798/how-to-add-work-item-as-child-to-parent)).

I did talk to Veracode team, however this feature isn't currently available. We can add custom Tags however.

TL:DR: How can I, via pipeline automation, query for certain work items in azureboards, and link them as a parent/child to a certain created epic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why the answer you found along with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-link) isn't enough to figure this out.

Comment: You're right. I missed that. Now I'll search how can I query the work items and then link them. TY

Comment: @Ricardo Lima I'm not sure if you want to use [Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-results-of-a-flat-work-item-query.) to get work items. What conditions are you going to use to get this created work item? Feel free to let me know if you're still blocked, I'll try my best to help.

Comment: @Ricardo Lima Hope you are doing well. Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue? Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT Thank you very much! In this case, I cant expect the exactly number of how many work items I'm going to update. Currently, I'm trying to find a way to determine how many times the call would be executed based on the json that Wiql returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [update work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-link) REST API to add a link between two work items. Since you are using REST API in the pipeline, you can use run your REST API in a PowerShell task. Here is the sample of adding a child link to an existing work item:

```
$organization = "{Organization name}" 
$project = "{Project name}" 
$pat = "{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/{Work item id}?api-version=5.1" 
$contentType = "application/json-patch+json"
$body= @'
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward",//Add a child link
      ##"rel": "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",//Add a parent link
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{Organization name}/{Project name}/_apis/wit/workItems/{Work item id}"
    }
  }
]
'@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PATCH -ContentType $contentType -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

You can find the Work Item Relation Types with [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20relation%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

If you want to query the work items, you can try to use Wiql. Please refer to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-results-of-a-flat-work-item-query.).