# How to associate a work item with a test result using the Azure DevOps API?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have read through the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/requirements-traceability?view=azure-devops), but I still cannot figure out how a custom Azure DevOps task can associate a test result with a work item **programmatically**. I built a custom task that executes tests (running and executing outside Azure DevOps). When the tests finish and the results come back, I get the list of associated work items as well. I would like to call the appropriate Azure DevOps API to associate the test result with one or more work items. Any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add work item as child to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50518798/how-to-add-work-item-as-child-to-parent)

Answer (score 1):

**Test Result is** also a kind of **work item**.

Thus you could use Rest API to handle this.

1. Use the [Get Test Results REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get the test case from the
   test result that you want to link to the work item:
2. Use the [Get Work Item REST API](http://GET%20https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/wit/workitems/%7Bid%7D?api-version=6.0) to get the existing relations of
   the work item (user story, task, etc) that you'd like to link to the
   test result, and determine if the test result and/or test case are
   already linked to the work item:
3. Uses the [Update Work Item REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to link the test result
   and/or
   test case to the work item:

More details of the sample and code snippet please refer Tanyan Harmon's comment in this related user voice:  [**Need ability to link Test Results back to ANY work item type, especially User Stories**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/451436/need-ability-to-link-test-results-back-to-any-work.html)

You could also follow the link shared by Matt in the comment.

Comment: Thank you! I have a chicken and egg problem. I developing a Pipeline task that writes out test results using the azure-pipelines-task-lib/task library. Excerpts: 
tp = new task.TestPublisher('JUnit');
tp.publish(...)
How do I get all the parameters needed on the above REST API calls? The examples in the task docs do not go into this detail.

Comment: @BertoldKolic In your situation, instead of Rest API, Kindly check if this helps: https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/04/04/azure-devops-rest-api-16-create-test-results-linked-to-a-test-plan/

Answer (score 1):

Check this extension that **I have created** https://github.com/JanuszNowak/janono.ado.testcase.associate.cli
it **allows associating in automatic manner**. Code sample:

```
namespace ExampleTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    [janono.ado.testcase.associate.Organization("janono-pub")]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [janono.ado.testcase.associate.TestCase(5)] //<---
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //yours test method content
            //...
            //
        }
    }
}
```